# close a ContentDialog after LostFocus on it and click on the MainPage Interface

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have used a ContentDialog to create a PopUp ContentDialog like the one in the Groove App:

[image]

the problem is that,I can't close it when I click on any part of the MainPage Interface and loose focus,I have tried like this,but it doesn't work :(,it closes only after I send data from the ContentDialog

MainPage.xaml:

```
private void MenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            AddFavoris formTask = new AddFavoris();
            t = formTask.ShowAsync();
            string f = formTask.Opgave;
            formTask.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(formTask_LostFocus);

       }


private void formTask_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Cancel();
        }
```

so,is there any solutions can I use to have a ContrentDialog that will be closed after a Click on the MainPage interface and lost focus on it 
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flyout instead of using a ContentDialog. Flyouts can be dismissed by tapping or clicking somewhere outside the flyout.

For more information: [Guidelines for flyouts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh465341.aspx), [Guidelines for dialog controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/dn997764.aspx)